# Always getting "Gas Estimation failed" in Remix when testing 1inch swap function

Tags: remix, tokens, ether, ganache

I am trying to test [1inch](https://github.com/1inch-exchange/1inchProtocol) swap function from the contract deployed via Remix on a Ganache fork of the Ethereum Mainnet. When calling this function I always get the "Gas estimation failed" error and "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert" error in Remix. My contract has enough sold off token (USDC) and Ether.

The interface of the swap function looks as follows:

```
function swap(
            IERC20 fromToken,
            IERC20 toToken,
            uint256 amount,
            uint256 minReturn,
            uint256[] memory distribution,
            uint256 featureFlags
        ) public payable;
```

The contract code:

```
contract TradeBot {
// OneSplit Config
    address ONE_SPLIT_ADDRESS = 0xC586BeF4a0992C495Cf22e1aeEE4E446CECDee0E;
    uint256 PARTS = uint256(10);
    uint256 FLAGS = uint256(0);

   function oneSplitSwap(address _from, address _to, uint256 _amount, uint256 _minReturn, 
                        uint256[] memory _distribution) public payable {
        _oneSplitSwap(_from, _to, _amount, _minReturn, _distribution);
    }

   function _oneSplitSwap(address _from, address _to, uint256 _amount, uint256 _minReturn, 
                          uint256[] memory _distribution) internal {
        // Setup contracts
        IERC20 _fromIERC20 = IERC20(_from);
        IERC20 _toIERC20 = IERC20(_to);
        IOneSplit _oneSplitContract = IOneSplit(ONE_SPLIT_ADDRESS);
        // Approve tokens
        _fromIERC20.approve(ONE_SPLIT_ADDRESS, _amount);
        // Swap tokens: give _from, get _to
        _oneSplitContract.swap(_fromIERC20, _toIERC20, _amount, _minReturn, _distribution, 
                               FLAGS);
        // Reset approval
        _fromIERC20.approve(ONE_SPLIT_ADDRESS, 0);
}
```

I test the function with the following parameters:

```
fromToken: 0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48 // USDC
toToken:   0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F // DAI
amount:    100000000
minReturn: 10 
distribution: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

Can't figure out why this does not work. All parameters seem to be correct and the contract has
enough USDC. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

After checking some successful transactions I used the FLAGS parameter set to "4406099890176" instead of default 0 and it worked. However, it does not work with the default 0 flag value. Also, had to use addresses instead of IERC20 types for "from" and "to" parameters.

Comment: To begin with, I'd try with passing `minReturn` as `0`. Or better yet (if you don't wanna lose what you have), find out what this value should be by calling the `getExpectedReturn` function (or some function with a similar name) on the same contract.

Comment: @goodvibration thanks for your suggestion. I tried both setting to 0 and returnValue but get the same result: "Gas estimation failed" and "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert". I also tried setting minReturn to something above the expected return value to trigger revert with a valuable message but it seems that the revert causing the trouble happens before the actual returnAmount - minAmount comparison. Do you have any other ideas? I don't get how this simple function could not possibly work. Might be something wrong with the contract code. I'll appreciate your help.

Comment: It's not that simple though. The function in `_oneSplitContract` calls a function in yet another contract (a proxy of some sort), which then calls the actual function via delegate call, which, if reverts, then reverts without an error-message. It's all on Etherscan, so you can follow the code just like I did, and you might come up with some other insights.

Comment: @goodvibration did you find it in the 1inch contract source code on Etherscan?

Comment: Of course, where else?

Comment: I am not sure, I thought may be you followed some transaction (I don't know how it works yet)

Comment: I started from `0xC586BeF4a0992C495Cf22e1aeEE4E446CECDee0E` on Etherscan, reviewed function `swap` on that contract's source code, saw that it was calling some other function on some other contract, when to the Read Contract tab, found the address of that other contract, and applied the same process on the address of that contract (viewing on Etherscan, etc).

Comment: @goodvibration thanks, I found the address of this oneSplitImpl contract. I'll try to debug.

Comment: NP. In order to improve your question, you may wanna post more specific details, focusing on the actual problem that you conclude following your debug session (i.e., instead of relying on others to do that investigation via Etherscan).

Comment: @goodvibration thank you, updated the question with my finding. It has something to do with flags and the way we pass token addresses  but I am not sure. I made it work by changing the FLAGS value and passing tokens as addresses.